# Method of finding all non-trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Z_{14}}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{21}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have the following question :

Find all non-trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Z_{14}}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{21}}$ 
I wonder how to solve such problems when the groups are pretty big to check the definition of each possibility.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought about the image of such a homomorphism? Probably you have some theorems about that.

Comment: If $C$ is a cyclic group generated by $\sigma$ and $G$ is any other group then homomorphisms $C\to G$ correspond to places to send $\sigma$ to...

Comment: Also an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45663/quick-way-to-find-the-number-of-the-group-homomorphisms-phi-bf-z-3-to-bf-z).

Comment: $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_n \to G$ is an homomorphism iff $ord(\phi(1)) \ \mid \ n$, and it is non-trivial iff $ord(\phi(1)) > 1$.